# How to go stop animating and load the next view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I have a view controller that displays some images as the app launches, but i don't know how to tell it to go to the TableViewController once the loop is complete...

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    launchAnimation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Animation1.png"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Animation2.png"],
                                          nil];

    [launchAnimation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    launchAnimation.animationDuration = 10;
    [launchAnimation startAnimating];
    how to go to a TableViewController? ??????


}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are running this code way too early. `viewDidLoad` means your view isn't even in the interface yet! Give the view a chance to get into the interface before you start animating and before you think about navigating to some other view.

Second, let's define the problem. Is it that you want to do this animation and *then* navigate? Then you will need to delay 10 seconds before you navigate (because that is how long the animation takes). So you could use delayed performance to do that.

Alternatively, use Core Animation or view animation, not UIImageView animation, because they give you a callback on completion of the animation (and UIImageView animation, as I think you've realized, does not).

Comment: Various ways of doing delayed performance: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_delayed_performance

Comment: i don't care about the delay, i just wanna go to the next view controller

Comment: Then go. Of course, how you do that depends upon what you mean by "go", whether you are using a storyboard, etc. etc. But by all means do not do it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: ok what do i type to tell my view that go to the next view automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple..

```
NSArray *arrImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Animation1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Animation2.png"], nil];
[launchAnimation setAnimationImages:arrImages];

float animationDuration=10.0f;
int repeatCount=1;
int totalImages=[arrImages count];

[launchAnimation setAnimationRepeatCount:repeatCount];
[launchAnimation setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
[launchAnimation startAnimating];

float delayTime= animationDuration* repeatCount* totalImages;
[self performSelector:@selector(gotoTableViewController) withObject:Nil afterDelay: delayTime];

-(void)gotoTableViewController
{
    //push TableViewController Here
}
```

Comment: oh i like your post :P, in the push table view, you put what? goto tableview?

Comment: Yes, push `TableViewController` mean goto tableView. Put your code to goto tableViewController. push or modal what ever you want.